# Sorted Linked List using comparable in Java

Tags: java

I am writing a ordered linked list for an assignment.  We are using comparable, and I am struggling to get boolean add to work properly.  I have labored over this code for two weeks now, and I am going cross-eyed looking at the code.  I could really appreciate a fresh set of eyes on my code.

The code should work for Comparable data - both ints and String (not mixed though).  I can get close to making each work, but not one code that stands for all.  Please help me fix this, so the code works for either Strings or Ints.

**I am only allowed to alter the add(), remove() and OrderedListNode classes**

**Update** Thanks to parkydr, I was able to work out some of my issues, however, I am still getting a null point error.  I am testing both int and Strings.  If the String loop has a "<" in the while section then elements come back in reverse order.  I will be an error for ints with that though.  If I have >=, like parkydr said, then I get back the ints in proper order, but Strings get a null pointer error.  How do I get both to work together?

**Update2** the ints need to be in order, like in the code from AmitG.

**Edit** Does anyone have any ideas?

```
package dataStructures;

/**
*   Class OrderedLinkedList.
*
*   This class functions as a linked list, but ensures items are stored in ascending     
    order.
*
*/
public class OrderedLinkedList
{

/**************************************************************************
 * Constants
 *************************************************************************/

/** return value for unsuccessful searches */
private static final OrderedListNode NOT_FOUND = null;


/**************************************************************************
 * Attributes
 *************************************************************************/

/** current number of items in list */
private int theSize;

/** reference to list header node */
private OrderedListNode head;

/** reference to list tail node */
private OrderedListNode tail;

/** current number of modifications to list */
private int modCount;


/**************************************************************************
 * Constructors
 *************************************************************************/


/**
 *  Create an instance of OrderedLinkedList.
 *
 */
public OrderedLinkedList()
{
    // empty this OrderedLinkedList
    clear();

}


/**************************************************************************
 * Methods
 *************************************************************************/


/*
 *  Add the specified item to this OrderedLinkedList.
 *
 *  @param  obj     the item to be added
 */
public boolean add(Comparable obj){
   OrderedListNode node = new OrderedListNode(obj);
   OrderedListNode head2 = new OrderedListNode(obj);
   OrderedListNode tail2 = new OrderedListNode(obj);
       if (head2 == null)
       {
           head2 = node;
           tail2 = node;
           return true;
       }


       // When the element to be added is less than the first element in the list
       if (obj.compareTo(head2.theItem) < 0)
       {
           node.next = head2;
           head2 = node;
           return true;
       }

       // When the element to be added is greater than every element in in list
       // and has to be added at end of the list
       if (obj.compareTo(tail2.theItem) > 0)
       {
           tail2.next = node;
           tail2 = node;
           return true;
       }

       //When the element to be added lies between other elements in the list
       if (obj.compareTo(head2.theItem) >= 0 && obj.compareTo(tail2.theItem) <= 0)
       {
          OrderedListNode current = head.next;
          OrderedListNode previous = head;
          while (obj.compareTo(current.theItem) >= 0)
          {
              previous = current;
              current = current.next;
          }
          previous.next = node;
          node.next = current;

       }

       return true;
   }  

/*
 *  Remove the first occurrence of the specified item from this   
            OrderedLinkedList.
 *
 *  @param  obj     the item to be removed
 */
public boolean remove(Comparable obj)
{
   OrderedListNode curr = head;
       OrderedListNode prev = head;

       while(curr != null && ! (curr.theItem.compareTo(obj) == 0)){
       prev = curr;
       curr = curr.next;
       }
       if(curr == null)
      return false;
       else{
          prev.next = curr.next;
          curr = null;
          return true;
     }  
  }



/**
 *  Empty this OrderedLinkedList.
 */
public void clear()
{
    // reset header node
    head = new OrderedListNode("HEAD", null, null);

        // reset tail node
        tail = new OrderedListNode("TAIL", head, null);

        // header references tail in an empty LinkedList
        head.next = tail;

        // reset size to 0
    theSize = 0;

    // emptying list counts as a modification
    modCount++;
}


/**
 *  Return true if this OrderedLinkedList contains 0 items.
 */
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return theSize == 0;
}


/**
 *  Return the number of items in this OrderedLinkedList.
 */
public int size()
{
    return theSize;
}


/*  
 *  Return a String representation of this OrderedLinkedList.
 *
 *  (non-Javadoc)
 *  @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
@Override
public String toString()
{
    String s = "";

    OrderedListNode currentNode = head.next;

    while (currentNode != tail)
    {
        s += currentNode.theItem.toString();

        if (currentNode.next != tail)
        {
            s += ", ";
        }

        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }

    return s;
}


/**************************************************************************
 * Inner Classes
 *************************************************************************/


/**
 *  Nested class OrderedListNode.
 *
 *  Encapsulates the fundamental building block of an OrderedLinkedList
 *  contains a data item, and references to both the next and previous nodes
 *  in the list
 */


// TODO: Implement the nested class OrderedListNode (5 points).  This nested class
// should be similar to the nested class ListNode of the class LinkedList, but
// should store a data item of type Comparable rather than Object.
    public static class OrderedListNode {


    Comparable theItem;   
        OrderedListNode next;
        OrderedListNode prev;


        OrderedListNode( Comparable theItem ) { this( theItem, null, null ); }

        OrderedListNode( Comparable theItem, OrderedListNode prev, OrderedListNode next)
        {
           this.theItem = theItem;         
           this.next = next;        
           this.prev = prev;
        }

        Comparable getData() { return theItem; }

        OrderedListNode getNext() { return next; }

        OrderedListNode getPrev() { return prev; }

        }
  // Remove - for testing only
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
     OrderedLinkedList list = new OrderedLinkedList();
     list.add("1");
     list.add("4");
     list.add("3");
     list.add("33");
     list.add("4");
     System.out.println(list.toString());

   }

 }
```

This above code works for ints for the most part except that items are stored as strings lexically.  So I need help fixing that.  I also need to make this code work with Strings as well.  Right now the below code works with String but not ints, it also stores in reverse order since the <= changes in the while statement.  Help!

Notice that the change in sign will make Strings work (albeit in reverse order):

```
  while (obj.compareTo(current.theItem) <= 0)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I get this code to compile and sort properly?

Comment: Do a little google search first. Assuming you have everything ready, follow this http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html You can use eclipse for this.

Comment: As far as I can see, it compiles just fine (using Java 6). You should take a look at the code that tries to insert an item somewhere between head and tail. Good luck!

Comment: I need help getting the code to actually sort items that are added.  I am using JGrasp already.

Comment: ordered list is different thing and sorted list different thing. What do you want? Ordered list means it keeps the order of insertion. `java.util.ArrayList` is ordered list.

Comment: Thanks mthmulders. Do the compareTo in between items look alright?

Comment: AmitG - well I put ordered list since that is the assignment name, but in that case I need a sorted list.  Thanks.

Comment: Depending on the test - either the head or the tail prints after running through the toString().  How do I eliminate this?

Comment: Can anyone give me some help sorting out my HEAD and TAIL elements, so that they don't print? Thanks.

Comment: Not to degrade your code, but an array would be best. Then you could utilize binary searching to make the most out of this collection. Even then, you could use a binary-searching-algorithm to find the correct location when adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my latest version of add.  It does not set up the prev links (I'll leave that as an "exercise for the reader").

```
   public boolean add(Comparable obj){
       OrderedListNode node = new OrderedListNode(obj);

       // When the list is empty
       if (head.next == tail)
       {
           head.next = node;
           node.next = tail;
           tail.prev = node;
           return true;
       }


       // When the element to be added is less than the first element in the list
       if (obj.compareTo(head.next.theItem) < 0)
       {
           node.next = head.next;
           head.next = node;
           return true;
       }

       //When there is an element in the list

       OrderedListNode current = head.next;
       OrderedListNode previous = head;
       while (current != tail && node.theItem.compareTo(current.theItem) >= 0)
       {
          previous = current;
          current = current.next;
       }

       previous.next = node;
       node.next = current;

       return true;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks parkydr, I have made the change.  I still run into a problem though with my HEAD and TAIL printing.  When I do a println(list) one or the other prints every time.  How do I avoid this, while keeping the elements sorted?

Comment: parkydr - I made that change as well as added a head2 and tail2.  Now I am getting a null pointer exception on the very line you edited above.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You shouldn't need any more heads or tails. The problem is you've created a head and tail node, start with them as null so they just point to first and last nodes of the list.

Comment: I have removed the head2 and tail2, but when entering items now they still print the HEAD or TAIL.  How do I get the additional elements to be added without printing HEAD and TAIL?

Comment: Note: >= has changed to > otherwise not a null pointer exception trying to get null.next

Comment: parkydr,
I really appreciate all your help.  In my assignment, I am only supposed to modify the boolean add(), boolean remove() and the OrderedListNode.  So I am not supposed to edit the clear() method.  Can you help me find an alternative solution within the boolean add() method?

Comment: The comparison was your main problem. HEAD is printed, because you are comparing against head when inserting and all the number characters come before H.  Just change add to start with head.next instead of head.  You also need to avoid comparing with tail.theItem. Note: head and tail should not change, just there next/prev references.

Comment: parkydr I am still struggling with this.  I have tried to make sure that I avoid the HEAD and TAIL by using head2 and tail2, but I am still have the problem with the sign on the while loop that you mentioned.  If there comparable is an int, then it must be >=, but if it is a String then it must be <.  Otherwise I get an error.  How do I fix this so BOTH work with the same code?

Comment: Answer updated with my solution. It works for ints and strings.

Comment: parkydr - thanks a lot for the help!  You made my weekend! Really, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Modified program, output will be `1,3,33,4,4`

if you want output like `1,3,4,4,33`  then remove `line 1` and `line 2` from the following program and paste following code. `Add` and `toString` methods are modified.

```
int currentValue = Integer.parseInt(freshNode.theItem.toString());  
int tempValue = Integer.parseInt(nodeToTraverse.theItem.toString());
if(currentValue>tempValue)
```

**Complete code**

```
/**
 * Class OrderedLinkedList.
 * 
 * This class functions as a linked list, but ensures items are stored in
 * ascending order.
 * 
 */
public class OrderedLinkedList {

    /**************************************************************************
     * Constants
     *************************************************************************/

    /** return value for unsuccessful searches */
    private static final OrderedListNode NOT_FOUND = null;

    /**************************************************************************
     * Attributes
     *************************************************************************/

    /** current number of items in list */
    private int theSize;

    /** reference to list header node */
    private OrderedListNode head;

    /** reference to list tail node */
    private OrderedListNode tail;

    /** current number of modifications to list */
    private int modCount;

    /**************************************************************************
     * Constructors
     *************************************************************************/

    /**
     * Create an instance of OrderedLinkedList.
     * 
     */
    public OrderedLinkedList() {
        // empty this OrderedLinkedList
//       clear();  //work around with this method. Removed temporarily.

    }

    /**************************************************************************
     * Methods
     *************************************************************************/

    /*
     * Add the specified item to this OrderedLinkedList.
     * 
     * @param obj the item to be added
     */
    public void add(Comparable obj) {
        OrderedListNode freshNode = new OrderedListNode(obj);
        if (head == null) {
            head = freshNode;
            tail = freshNode;
            return;
        }
        OrderedListNode nodeToTraverse = head;
        while(nodeToTraverse!=null)
        {
            int result = freshNode.theItem.compareTo(nodeToTraverse.theItem);  // line 1
            if(result>0)   // line 2
            {
                if(nodeToTraverse.next==null)
                {
                    nodeToTraverse.next=freshNode;
                    freshNode.prev =nodeToTraverse;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    nodeToTraverse=nodeToTraverse.next;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                nodeToTraverse.prev.next = freshNode;
                freshNode.prev = nodeToTraverse.prev;
                freshNode.next= nodeToTraverse;
                nodeToTraverse.prev=freshNode;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Remove the first occurrence of the specified item from this
     * OrderedLinkedList.
     * 
     * @param obj the item to be removed
     */
    public boolean remove(Comparable obj) {
        OrderedListNode curr = head;
        OrderedListNode prev = head;

        while (curr != null && !(curr.theItem.compareTo(obj) == 0)) {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        if (curr == null)
            return false;
        else {
            prev.next = curr.next;
            curr = null;
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Empty this OrderedLinkedList.
     */
    public void clear() {
        // reset header node
        head = new OrderedListNode("HEAD", null, null);

        // reset tail node
        tail = new OrderedListNode("TAIL", head, null);

        // header references tail in an empty LinkedList
        head.next = tail;

        // reset size to 0
        theSize = 0;

        // emptying list counts as a modification
        modCount++;
    }

    /**
     * Return true if this OrderedLinkedList contains 0 items.
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return theSize == 0;
    }

    /**
     * Return the number of items in this OrderedLinkedList.
     */
    public int size() {
        return theSize;
    }

    /*
     * Return a String representation of this OrderedLinkedList.
     * 
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = "";

        OrderedListNode temp = head;
        while (temp != null) {
            s = s + temp.theItem.toString()+",";
            temp = temp.next;
        }

        return s.substring(0,s.lastIndexOf(",")); //this will remove last comma
//      return s; //1,2,3,4,5,25,33, this will not remove last comma(,)
    }

    /**************************************************************************
     * Inner Classes
     *************************************************************************/

    /**
     * Nested class OrderedListNode.
     * 
     * Encapsulates the fundamental building block of an OrderedLinkedList
     * contains a data item, and references to both the next and previous nodes
     * in the list
     */

    // TODO: Implement the nested class OrderedListNode (5 points). This nested
    // class
    // should be similar to the nested class ListNode of the class LinkedList,
    // but
    // should store a data item of type Comparable rather than Object.

    // Remove - for testing only
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OrderedLinkedList list = new OrderedLinkedList();
        /*list.add("1");
        list.add("4");
        list.add("3");
        list.add("33");
        list.add("5");
        list.add("2");
        list.add("25");*/
        list.add("1");
         list.add("4");
         list.add("3");
         list.add("33");
         list.add("4");

        System.out.println(list.toString());
    }

    private static class OrderedListNode {
        Comparable data;
        Comparable theItem;
        OrderedListNode next;
        OrderedListNode prev;

        OrderedListNode(Comparable data) {
            this(data, null, null);
        }

        OrderedListNode(Comparable data, OrderedListNode prev, OrderedListNode next) {
            this.theItem = data;
            this.next = next;
            this.prev = prev;
        }

        Comparable getData() {
            return data;
        }

        OrderedListNode getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        OrderedListNode getPrev() {
            return prev;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return (String)theItem;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: AmitG, thanks a lot for the help.  The changes that you made still don't for Strings.  I can get these to work for ints or String, but not for both.  Any ideas?

Comment: Also, I need to only alter add(), remove() and OrderedListNode.  You removed the clear() methor from the code.

Comment: This code also gives an error when the initial int is greater than 1.

Comment: hmm. Good catch. Now I am looking for answer :-)

Comment: AmitG, did you come up with anything or are you as frustrated as I am?

Comment: I hope somebody will copy and paste my program in eclipse/netbean and run it. It is working for the current condition only. But it fails on conditions given by above comment by OP user. A kind of bug we can say.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class List {

    private Node head;
    private int manyNodes;

    public List() {
        head = null;
        manyNodes = 0;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return ((head == null) && (manyNodes == 0));
    }

    public void add(int element) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node(element, null);
            manyNodes++;
        } else {
            head.addNodeAfter(element);
            manyNodes++;
        }
    }

    public boolean remove(int target) {
        boolean removed = false;

        Node cursor = head;
        Node precursor;

        if (head == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Cannot remove from empty list");
        }

        if (head.getInfo() == target) {
            head = head.getNodeAfter();
            manyNodes--;
            removed = true;
        } else {
            precursor = cursor;
            cursor = cursor.getNodeAfter();

            while ((cursor != null) && (!removed)) {
                if (cursor.getInfo() == target) {
                    precursor.removeNodeAfter();
                    manyNodes--;
                    removed = true;
                } else {
                    precursor = cursor;
                    cursor = cursor.getNodeAfter();
                }
            }
        }

        return removed;
    }

    public Node getFront() {
        return head;
    }

    public int size() {
        return manyNodes;
    }

    public Node listSort(Node source) {
        source = head;

        int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int smallest;

        Node front;

        while (source != null) {
            if (source.getInfo() > largest) {
                largest = source.getInfo();
            }

            source = source.getNodeAfter();
        }

        front = new Node(Node.find(head, largest).getInfo(), null);
        remove(largest);

        while (!isEmpty()) {
            source = head;
            smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

            while (source != null) {
                if (source.getInfo() <= smallest) {
                    smallest = source.getInfo();
                }

                source = source.getNodeAfter();
            }

            remove(smallest);
            front.addNodeAfter(smallest);
        }

        head = front.reverse(front);
        source = head;
        return source;
    }

    public void showList() {
        Node cursor = head;

        if (cursor == null) {
            System.out.println("This list contains no items.");
        } else {
            while (cursor != null) {
                System.out.print(cursor.getInfo() + " ");
                cursor = cursor.getNodeAfter();
            }
        }
    }

}//end class List
```